# Customize the WinXP/7 logon screen behaviors

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, login, active-directory, group-policy

How customizable is the Windows XP/7 logon screen via group policy? For example, can I do any of the following:

1. Display a custom error message on logon failure?
2. Popup a custom app that launches minimal functionality (i.e. a user guide app)?

I can obviously replace the Windows logon GINA to achieve complete control over the logon, but I don't want to go down such a complex route...

Answer (score 1):

You are right in that the best way to customize the logon process is to [create your own version of GINA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/windows/desktop/aa375457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Another alternative for `Windows XP` is to hack the `C:\Windows\System32\logonui.exe` file. Make a backup of the `logonui.exe` file, then use [`Resource Hacker`](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) or other resource editors to edit the messages / bitmaps within the file. There is a [simple explanation here](http://www.overclockersclub.com/guides/windowsxplogonhack/).

### Kiosk Mode

You may want to investigate [Windows XP Kiosk Mode](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555463). You can enable it by editing the `Registry`, go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` and edit `Shell`, and replace the **Value** data with something like `iexplore -k http://www.yourcompany.com`

Microsoft used to ship [Windows Steady State](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_SteadyState), but unfortunately it is discontinued since July 2008. Here are [some alternatives](http://www.instantfundas.com/2010/09/5-alternatives-to-windows-steadystate.html).